# Postgres query to get current and previous prices of product from prices history

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, timescaledb

There are tables with products and it's prices history and there is a need to have single row with current and previous prices (if exists and not equals current) of each product.

Now, I have query with LATERAL JOINs (below) but it works very slow with 1mil of product and 40mils of records of prices history. Will be glad too see alternative solutions for the problem.

---

**Fiddle**

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5AZzotnUUgBnYoz2kkHSg/1

**Current query**

```sql
SELECT 
    products.id, 
    price.price as price, 
    price.created_at as price_created_at,
    prev_price.price as prev_price,
    prev_price.created_at as prev_price_created_at 
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT price, created_at
        FROM product_prices_history
        WHERE product_prices_history.product_id = products.id
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) price ON true
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT price, created_at
        FROM product_prices_history as prev_price 
        WHERE prev_price.product_id = products.id AND prev_price.price <> price.price
        ORDER BY created_at DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) prev_price ON true;
```

**Data**:

`products`

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

`products_prices_history`

| id | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.0 | '2023-01-01' |
| 2 | 10.0 | '2023-01-01' |
| 3 | 10.0 | '2023-01-01' |
| 1 | 100.0 | '2023-01-02' |
| 2 | 10.0 | '2023-01-02' |
| 3 | 10.0 | '2023-01-02' |
| 1 | 100.0 | '2023-01-03' |
| 2 | 2.0 | '2023-01-03' |
| 1 | 100.0 | '2023-01-04' |
| 2 | 2.0 | '2023-01-04' |
| 1 | 100.0 | '2023-01-05' |
| 2 | 2.0 | '2023-01-05' |

**Expected result**

| id | price | price_created_at | prev_price | prev_price_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.0 | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000Z |  |  |
| 2 | 2.0 | 2023-01-05T00:00:00.000Z | 10.0 | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |
| 3 | 10.0 | 2023-01-02T00:00:00.000Z |  |  |

Comment: you can try ```LAG()``` function which allows you access previous record based on the column you pass to the function. Please see the advanced queries you can write for analytics here [link](https://docs.timescale.com/use-timescale/latest/query-data/advanced-analytic-queries/)